# Display data from ng-repeat in multiple columns

Tags: angularjs, checklist-model

I'm getting list of data from Db to a view using ng-repeat. In order to select multiple values at once I'm using checklist-model. My code is as follows,

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<input type=checkbox checklist-model="user.role" checklist-value="item"/>{{item}}
</div>
```

This will return a long list one below another. What I need is to get these data in the list to be displayed in 4 columns. Any help please!

This was my previous question. For the answer for this I got this

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td ng-repeat="item in items">
          <input type=checkbox checklist-model="user.role" checklist-value="item"/>{{item}}
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

and this

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" style="display:inline-block;">
  <input type=checkbox checklist-model="user.role" checklist-value="item"/>{{item}}
</div>
```

These codes make sure that the data are in a same row. But what I want is to add values into 4 separate columns. If there are 1000 data I need 200 data to be in one column, 200 in the second and so on. Please not that I'm using checklist-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products" ng-if="$index % 3 == 0" class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4"> <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="user.role" checklist-value="{{products[$index]}}"/>{{products[$index]}}</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"> <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="user.role" checklist-value="{{products[$index]}}"/>{{products[$index+1]}}</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"> <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="user.role" checklist-value="{{products[$index]}}"/>{{products[$index+2]}}</div>
</div>
```

This did the trick. Thanks to @KhalidHussain

Comment: Won't that result in same checklist-value for each of the columns ?

IMO this approach is a trap since 'product' is not 'product' for each column,  even tricked up the author of this answer when writing it... not to mention the duplication of the checklist html.

Comment: You also need to check if 'products[$index+1]' or 'products[$index+2]' exists.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Please try this and use logic

```js
  var app = angular.module("app",[]);
    
    app.controller("MyCtrl" , function($scope){
      
      $scope.index = 0;
       $scope.items =["str1", "str2", "str3","str4","str5","str6","str7","str8","str9","str10"];
       $scope.array = [];
      for(var i=0; i<$scope.items.length/5;i++)
        $scope.array.push(i);
      });
```

```html
<html>
      <head>
        <title>My Angular App!</title>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
       
      </head>
      
      <body>
     
     
     
     <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
       
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Col1</td>
          <td>Col2</td>
          <td>Col3</td>
          <td>Col4</td>
       <td>Col5</td>
          </tr>
         <tr ng-repeat="i in array"  ng-init="index = i*5">
           
             <td ng-repeat="one in items.slice(index,index+5)">{{one}}</td>
         </tr>
     </table>
      
    </div>
    
     
     
      </body>
      
      
    </html>
```

Comment: @tharindusenanayake Hi use this login and add your customization, replace "5" to "4"

Comment: Thanks @NikhilVaghela. I tried it. But the problem is the the data I'm passing is form a $scope object. When I use that it does not work. For the array it does. Is there a way for me to convert that $scope object in to a array?

Comment: Please make full demo then i will may be help

Comment: I'm receiving data from a web api using get method. That has value attributes of ID and Name. 
this is the method i'm using
 `var pramiseGet = angularService.GetProducts();
    
    
       pramiseGet.then(function (pl) {
            $scope.Products = pl.data;
           console.log($scope.Products);
        }`

Comment: replace items to product, need more help require demo 

this demo try in your local and modification as per your requirement